# Create arrays in shared memory w/o templates like in PyOpenCL

Tags: cuda, pycuda

How can I create an array in shared memory without modifying the kernel using templates as seen in the [official examples](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/MatrixmulTiled). Or is using templates the official way?

In PyOpenCL I can create an array in local memory with setting a kernel argument

```
kernel.set_arg(1,numpy.uint32(a_width))

... 
KERNEL_CODE = """
__kernel void matrixMul(__local float* A_temp,...)
    { ...} """
```

Comment: Your tag is missleading. You look for help for OpenCL and not for CUDA.

Comment: I am looking for feature in PyCUDA which exists in PyOpenCL as well as in CUDA. I tried to tag it 'PyCUDA', but the tag does not exist yet.

Comment: I had been meaning to add a tag for PyCUDA for a while. Now done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA supports dynamic shared memory allocation at kernel run time, but the mechanism is a bit different to OpenCL. In the CUDA runtime API, a kernel using dynamically allocated/sized shared memory and the launch to size the memory uses the following syntax:

```
__global__ void kernel(...)
{
    extern __shared__ typename buffer[];

    ....
}
....
kernel <<< griddim, blockdim, sharedmem, streamID >>> (...)
```

where `sharedmem` is the total number of bytes per block which will be allocated to buffer.

In PyCUDA, the same mechanism works something like this:

```
mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void kernel(...)
    {
        extern __shared__ typename buffer[];

        ....
    }
  """)

func = mod.get_function("kernel")
func.prepare(..., shared=sharedmem)
func.prepared_call(griddim,blockdim,...)
```

with the shared memory allocation size passed to the `prepare` method.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the question fully. I do not work with Python, but know OpenCL quite well.

In OpenCL you have two possibilities to create shared/local memory buffers:

1) You add a kernel parameter as you have it in you question.
2) Do define a buffer statically within the kernel itself like:

```
__local buffer[1024];
```

There are no other chances to do this with OpenCL. How you create the kernel code string to pass it to OpenCL is another question and related to Python. I am not an expert on this.