# How to use the `prepare` function from PyCUDA

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I have problems passing the right parameters to the [`prepare` function](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Function.prepare) (and to the prepared_call) to [allocate of shared memory in PyCUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468132/create-arrays-in-shared-memory-w-o-templates-like-in-pyopencl/6491754#6491754). I understand the error message in this way, that one of the variables I pass to PyCUDA is a `long` instead of what I intended `float32`. But I cannot see, where the variable comes from.

Furthermore does it seem to me, that the [official example](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html#prepared-invocations) and the [documentation of `prepare`](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html?highlight=prepare#pycuda.driver.Function.prepare) contradict each other regarding if `block` needs to be `None` or not.

```
from pycuda import driver, compiler, gpuarray, tools
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np

kernel_code ="""
__device__ void loadVector(float *target, float* source, int dimensions )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++ ) target[i] = source[i];
}
__global__ void kernel(float* data, int dimensions, float* debug)
{
    extern __shared__ float mean[];
    if(threadIdx.x == 0) loadVector( mean, &data[0], dimensions );
    debug[threadIdx.x]=  mean[threadIdx.x];
}
"""

dimensions = 12
np.random.seed(23)
data = np.random.randn(dimensions).astype(np.float32)
data_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(data)
debug = gpuarray.zeros(dimensions, dtype=np.float32)

mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code)
kernel = mod.get_function("kernel")
kernel.prepare("PiP",block = (dimensions, 1, 1),shared=data.size)
grid = (1,1)
kernel.prepared_call(grid,data_gpu,dimensions,debug)
print debug.get()
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "shared_memory_minimal_example.py", line 28, in <module>
kernel.prepared_call(grid,data_gpu,dimensions,debug)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycuda-0.94.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/driver.py", line 230, in function_prepared_call
func.param_setv(0, pack(func.arg_format, *args))
pycuda._pvt_struct.error: cannot convert argument to long
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create arrays in shared memory w/o templates like in PyOpenCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468132/create-arrays-in-shared-memory-w-o-templates-like-in-pyopencl)

Comment: I gave you an answer which explains how to do this is [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468132/create-arrays-in-shared-memory-w-o-templates-like-in-pyopencl/6491754#6491754) you posted about a month ago.

Comment: Please update the **question** to include the new code and information

Comment: Hi Talonmies, I updated the whole question. Thanks for your patients.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this same problem and it took my a while to work out the answer so here goes. The cause of the error message is that data_gpu is a GPUArray instance, i.e. you made it with

```
data_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(data)
```

To pass it to prepared_call you need to do data_gpu.gpudata to get the associated [DeviceAllocation](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray.gpudata) instance (i.e. effectively the pointer to the device memory location).

Also, passing a block argument to prepare is now [deprecated](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Function.prepare) - so a correct invocation would be something like this:

```
data_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(data)
func.prepare( "P" )
grid = (1,1)
block = (1,1,1)
func.prepared_call( grid, block, data_gpu.gpudata )
```